# adding specific value from a hashmap with a user defined object as value

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap which is in the form `<gameID, Achievement>` in which Achievement is a user defined object which holds an AchievementID, AchievementName, and AchievementPoints:

```
[1003901=(901, Shoot 'em up, 100), 1001902=(902, Tango down, 15)]
```

I would like to add up the values based on AchievementPoints for the entire game, so in this case, I would add up 100 and 15. I tried to iterate through using the for each loop, however, I can't seem to figure out how to access the AchievementPoints member specifically and just use that value. Is there any way to just iterate through the hashmap and just add values based on a specific member of the object value?

Edit 1:
sorry, to clarify, my gameID is actually a combination where the first four numbers are the actual gameID and the next 3 are the achievementID. This was done to keep the id unique. That is why I would add both of those

Comment: Why would you add 100 and 15, aren't they for different games? It seems `Map<gameId, Achievement>` only stores 1 achievement per game?
Is [HashMap.values()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29) what you need?

Comment: sorry, to clarify, my gameID is actually a combination where the first four numbers are the actual gameID and the next 3 are the achievementID. This was done to keep the id unique. That is why I would add both of those

Comment: I see..kind of.. Well, I'll cook up an answer for you but I'll suggest a slightly different structure.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it. I have just been stuck on this little tidbit for a while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Java 8, if you simply want to add up all the values in the map, you could do something like this:

```
achievementMap.values().stream().mapToInt(a -> a.getAchievmentPoints()).sum();
```

This creates a stream that iterates over all the values in the map, performs a transformation of the `Achievement` instance to an integer value, selecting the `achievementPoints` property of the object and then sums it all up.

Comment: This works like a charm and was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help. Also thanks to everyone else for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is more or less what you're intending: you have multiple games, each game having multiple achievements: a `Map<Integer,List<Achievement>`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main
{
    static class Achievement
    {
        private int id;

        private String name;

        private int score;

        public Achievement( int id, String name, int score )
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.score = score;
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Map<Integer, List<Achievement>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put( 1003, Arrays.asList( new Achievement( 901, "Shoot 'em up", 100 ) ) );
        map.put( 1001, Arrays.asList( new Achievement( 902, "Tango down", 15 ) ) );
        System.out.println( map.get( 1003 ).stream().mapToInt( ( a ) -> a.score ).sum() );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably not what you meant, is it? It seems you might actually have a List of Achievements, in which case you don't need a Map.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is sum all the points gathered through the game, assuming you use `encapsulation` in the `Achievement` class and there's a `getter` method for Achievement points then, what if you iterate through the `hashMap` like this:

```
int sum = 0;
 Iterator it = gameMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        sum += pair.getValue().getAchievementPoints();
    }
System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int total = 0;
HashMap<String,Achievement> map = new HashMap();
Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
  Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
  Achievement achievement = (Achievement) entry.getValue();

  //Once you have achievement Object, apply your custom logic here.
  total = total + achievement.achievementPoints;

}
```